# Post does save in the right folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bloc.io

I have a project a github which can be found here: https://github.com/marcvanderpeet12/bloccitmaster

I have the following problem:

- If I go here: http://localhost:3000/topics/2 and add a new post
- I save a post but its not saved in the right folder (I want it to be save in topics2 so next time I go to http://localhost:3000/topics/2 i see it there).

But it does not seem to save in the right folder. Any quick thoughts on what goes wrong?

Comment: WHat is wrong is that you are trying to save it in a file. Use database!

Comment: when asking, post relevant parts of code which produce unexpected results instead of repository link, not so much people would like to check it and dig into your sources

Answer (score 2):

You need to associate the topic to the post before you save. You do this by assigning the `topic` to your Post instance.

```
def create
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body))

  # Add this line
  @post.topic = @topic

  authorize @post
  if @post.save
    flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
    redirect_to [@topic, @post]
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post"
    render :new
  end
end
```